# Putting extra in Bundle causing weird conflict and app to crash... Why?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm facing a strange error in my main application activity.

I have a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in my activity (as an inner class), with its `instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)` method overridden to handle orientation changes.

This method worked fine until I put a String in a Bundle via `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`. When the method is implemented like so, `instantiateItem` is not called:

```
 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    if (myObject != null) {
        outState.putString(MY_OBJECT_KEY, myObject.getName());
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

When I remove `outState.putString(MY_OBJECT_KEY, myObject.getName())` instantiateItem is called without problem every time orientation is changed. Why is this? Any help is truly appreciated.

The error that I get is the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.android.miki.rpiplantsapp, PID: 22292                                     
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.miki.rpiplantsapp/com.android.miki.rpiplantsapp.PlantStatsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.android.miki.rpiplantsapp.MoistureFragment.setOptimalStatText(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.android.miki.rpiplantsapp.MoistureFragment.setOptimalStatText(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
       at com.android.miki.rpiplantsapp.PlantStatsActivity$ViewPageAdapter.updateCurrentFragsOptimal(PlantStatsActivity.java:733)
       at com.android.miki.rpiplantsapp.PlantStatsActivity.loadPlantItemTabs(PlantStatsActivity.java:426)
       at com.android.miki.rpiplantsapp.PlantStatsActivity.onCreate(PlantStatsActivity.java:225)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

instantiateItem method looks like this:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                MoistureFragment moistureTab = (MoistureFragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
                currentMoistureFragment = moistureTab;
                return currentMoistureFragment;

            case 1:
                LightFragment lightTab = (LightFragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
                currentLightFragment = lightTab;
                return currentLightFragment;
            case 2:
                TemperatureFragment tempTab = (TemperatureFragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
                currentTempFragment = tempTab;
                return currentTempFragment;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

updateCurrentFragsOptimal() looks like this:

```
   public void updateCurrentFragsOptimal(double moistureValue, double lightValue, double tempValue){
        currentMoistureFragment.setOptimalStatText(String.valueOf(moistureValue));
        currentLightFragment.setOptimalStatText(String.valueOf(lightValue));
        currentTempFragment.setOptimalStatText(String.valueOf(tempValue));
    }
```

Comment: What's the error that you get when the app crashes? Post the whole logcat of it here please.

Comment: Posted it now. The error that I get is due to trying to call a method on the MoistureFragment object, which is null, which is due to the instantiateItem() method not being called. When instantiateItem is called, I don't get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was simpler than I thought... I figured out that I called a method in my `onCreate()` method, when `savedInstanceState` wasn't null, that called another method. This method did several things that prevented `instantiateItem` from being called, and therefore a fragment ended up being null and caused a NullPointerException. Just a simple error in logic.

Answer (score 0):

While overriding onSaveInstanceState() you should call the superclass code before yours.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (myObject != null && outState != null) {
        outState.putString(MY_OBJECT_KEY, myObject.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that just now. Doesn't work unfortunately. instantiateItem is still not called.